# The Alternating Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The alternating group $A_4$ is generated by $\{(12)(34),(123)\}$. What does this actually mean? I'm having trouble understanding symmetric/alternating groups and dealing with elements and generators of them.

Comment: It means that any element in it can be written as a product of elements from the given set. Do you understand how those elements define permutations, and how those permutations can be multiplied by each other?

Answer (score 4):

In general if $M$ is a subset of the group $G$, then $$\langle M\rangle=\{x_1^{\epsilon_1}x_2^{\epsilon_2}...x_n^{\epsilon_n}\mid x_i\in M, \epsilon_i\in\mathbb Z, n=0,1,2...\}$$

Comment: I am always left wondering what the OP learned, but +1 for a nice answer!

Comment: Nice, concise, and sweet ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What it means is that $\{(1\ 2)(3\ 4),(1\ 2\ 3)\}$ is a *generating set* of $A_4$, or as it's sometimes written, $A_4 = \langle (1\ 2)(3\ 4), (1\ 2\ 3)\rangle$.

What this means is that every element in $A_4$ is a product of powers of the elements in the generating set, or in other words, if $a \in A_4$, then you can write $a$ entirely as some chain of products of powers of the elements in that generating set. (My earlier description was a little wrong).

Comment: That last definition of $a$ goes only for abelian groups. You need some minor correction since $(1\:2)(3\:4)$ and $(1\:2\:3)$ don't commute.

Comment: Ah, good catch! I will fix it!

Comment: Also, calling it "the" generating set is not correct, since there is not a unique set that generates the group.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Curse you, definite articles!

Comment: So, then, how would you go about showing that $A_4$ is generated by this set?

Comment: @user72195 You can just apply the definition. $A_4$ only has a handful of elements (how many?), and we can count unique combinations of products of the elements rather easily. Does this count equal the order of $A_4$?